# how can I adjust this div to not stretch the entire browser from left to right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a box around this login form but I can't figure out how to lose the stretch from left to right. Any pointers? I will include the code and screenshot below.[image]

```css
display          : flex; 
justify-content  : center; 
align-items      : center; 
margin           : 140px 0px 125px 0px;  
box-sizing       : content-box; 
border           : solid #2356a7 10px;
padding          : 5px; 
border-radius    : 20px; 
padding-top      : 20px; 
padding-bottom   : 20px; 
background-color : #f4f4f4;
```

Comment: You just need to set its `width`...

Comment: [Show your HTML..!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

you need to just add width, i'm not sure but i think it solve it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options here.

The easiest one is to add width and set auto margins:

```
width: 300px;
display:flex; 
justify-content: center; 
align-items: center; 
margin: 140px auto 125px;  
box-sizing: content-box; 
border: solid #2356a7 10px;
padding: 5px; 
border-radius: 20px; 
padding-top: 20px; 
padding-bottom: 20px; 
background-color: #f4f4f4;
```

Another one is to wrap this div into another one:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="form">...your form</div>
</div>
```

and add styles:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.form {
  display:flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center; 
  margin: 140px 0px 125px 0px;  
  box-sizing: content-box; 
  border: solid #2356a7 10px;
  padding: 5px; 
  border-radius: 20px; 
  padding-top: 20px; 
  padding-bottom: 20px; 
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
``
```